# Is it possible to utilize the LINQ portion of the foreach inside the loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this view in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<%
    var path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "uploads"); 
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path).OrderBy(f => new FileInfo(f).Length))
    {
        var item = new FileInfo(file);
%>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <%=Html.Encode(Path.GetFileName(item.Name))%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=Html.Encode(Functions.FormatBytes(item.Length))%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=Html.FileLink(item.Name)%>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Is it possible to access my variable `f` inside the loop, or is there some other way to do this so I do not have to dimension two instances of `FileInfo(file)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var fileInfos = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().OrderBy(f => f.Length);

foreach (var fileInfo in fileInfos)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your view is really overstepping it's responsibilities here. You should create a class that maps to what data you want to show in the view, then in your controller, retrieve the data and populate a IEnumerable<> of your classes and return that in the ViewModel, which your view can then just simple loop through.

Comment: Thanks john, I will do this. I am still learning MVC, so I appreciate your critiques :)